# Mocking a public method and a repository together

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class A, it has a dependency on a repository (maybe JPA repository).

```
Class A{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository somerepository;

    public int methodA() {
        somerepository.findAll();
        methodB();

    }

    public methodB() {
       //do something
    }

}
```

Now I want to write a test code that will mock the public methodB() and return some default value when its called. This can be done by mocking the ClassA bean.
Also I want to mock the repository so that when the repository findAll() method is called then some default value is returned ie mock repository and inject it into the ClassA bean.

Is there any way to fulfill both conditions?
Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Example Code:

    Class A{

    @Autowired
    SomeRepository somerepository;

    public int methodA(){

    somerepository.findAll();

    methodB(); //calls method B

    }

    public methodB(){
       //do something
    }

    }

Comment: you can "edit" your question to update it with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@Spy` for partial mocking(method B) and `@InjectMocks` to inject your mocked repository into your Class, something like this will work:

```
RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SpringDemoTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    ClassA classA;

    @Mock
    SomeRepository someRepository;

    @Test
    public void testMethodA()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this.getClass());

        Mockito.when(classA.methodB()).thenReturn(50);
        Mockito.when(someRepository.findAll()).thenReturn("This is a Mock!");

        Assert.assertEquals("This is a Mock!", classA.methodA());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use spy type for this.

```
A a = Mockito.spy(new A());
```

you can mock the method below:

```
when(a.methodB()).thenReturn(XXX);
```

or

```
doNothing().when(a).methodB();
```

Comment: Thanks, and how to mock the call to repository ?